# grep variable-length optional text

Tags: grep, perl

I would like to search for edge-anchored text that has a block of preceding optional text, any amount of which can be included in the match. For instance, supposing I am trying to find `^xyz` but would also accept `^wxyz`, `^vwxyz`, `^uvwxyz`, `^tuvwxyz`,  `^stuvwxyz`, `^rstuvwxyz`, but **no other possibilities** (for my actual search, I couldn't simply use a regex character sequence like `[r-w]` because the actual block of preceding characters are not in alphabetical order as in this simplified example), I could use the command `egrep '^r?s?t?u?v?w?xyz'`. Is there another way to write this search such that I could simply apply the optional flag (`?`) to the entire sequence rather than to each element individually?

Edit:

Here is an example of more realistic data:
The full text to be matched is AZHDEOIMOSJDJKEJLCN. However, letters are variably lost from the left end, so all the following should be matched:

```
^AZHDEOIMOSJDJKEJLCN
^ZHDEOIMOSJDJKEJLCN
^HDEOIMOSJDJKEJLCN
^DEOIMOSJDJKEJLCN
^EOIMOSJDJKEJLCN
^OIMOSJDJKEJLCN
^IMOSJDJKEJLCN
^MOSJDJKEJLCN
^OSJDJKEJLCN
^SJDJKEJLCN
^JDJKEJLCN
^DJKEJLCN
^JKEJLCN
^KEJLCN
```

Thus, the residual `KEJLCN` is essential and everything preceding it is optional. However, I cannot simply `grep` for `KEJLCN` because I only want instances that are anchored to the beginning of the line (`^`) and are optionally preceded by the other characters listed above. Also, note that the search string will be in a variable and the minimal residue (e.g., `KEJLCN`) will be extracted by a substring operation in a script (for example, in a perl environment, running `egrep` as a system command searching for the text `$query`, the essential text would be contained in `substr($query,-6)` and the optional preceding text would be contained in `substr($query,0,length($query)-6`). Therefore, the solution should be valid for regex in variable form rather than for string literals only.

Comment: Could you provide more realistic data, if they aren't actually letters? `^[r-w]*xyz` matches your example. May characters/text blocks be repeated?

Comment: Are the strings going in alphabetical order?  For example, will you like to match `^ruvwxyz` or `^uvrwxyz`?

Comment: I added a more detailed example. Please let me know if that clarifies the matter. Thanks.

Comment: I'm still not understanding why you can't simply use `grep '^[A-Z]*KEJLCN'`

Comment: @steeldriver: This is because the preceding sequence is definite. For instance, I would not want to count `ZKEJLCN` as a valid result. If the file consists only of capital letters, then `grep '^[A-Z]*KEJLCN'` is equivalent to `grep KEJLCN`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
grep '[[:lower:]]*xyz'
```

Would return you all lines on which that pattern is matched. But, of course, this does not match explicit sequences of characters.

Still, that appears to be a problem you have already solved:

```
grep -f - <<\STRINGS /dev/fd/3 3<<\DATA
^ZHDEOIMOSJDJKEJLCN
^HDEOIMOSJDJKEJLCN
^DEOIMOSJDJKEJLCN
^EOIMOSJDJKEJLCN
^OIMOSJDJKEJLCN
^IMOSJDJKEJLCN
^MOSJDJKEJLCN
^OSJDJKEJLCN
^SJDJKEJLCN
^JDJKEJLCN
^DJKEJLCN
^JKEJLCN
^KEJLCN
STRINGS

SJDJKEJLCN                                                                  
JDJKEJLCN
o;aidsfjoasjif
KKEJnotLCN
DATA
```

#### OUTPUT

```
SJDJKEJLCN                                                                 
JDJKEJLCN
```

If you would like to programmatically generate the same lookup table...

```
grep -f - <<STRINGS /dev/fd/3 3<<\DATA
$(
    MATCH=ZHDEOIMOSJDJKEJLCN
    until [ ${#MATCH} -lt ${MINLEN=6} ]
    do  printf '^%s\n' "$MATCH"
        MATCH=${MATCH#?}
    done
)
STRINGS

SJDJKEJLCN                                                                  
JDJKEJLCN                                                                  
o;aidsfjoasjif                                                             
KKEJnotLCN                                                                 
DATA
```

#### OUTPUT

```
SJDJKEJLCN                                                                  
JDJKEJLCN
```

Comment: The problem is that it would also return, for example, `^axyz`, which is undesired.

Comment: Oh, that's an interesting solution: constructing the entire list of valid sequences and submitting all of them to `grep`. I was thinking of building a regex that represented the valid list, but simply searching for each individually would work equally well. Thanks.

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you know if it is possible to formulate the search in the language of regular expressions (i.e., can one construct a regex that equates to the family of search queries)? Or is the only solution to build the family of queries programmatically, as you have done?

Comment: @user001 - Well, I could do it with `sed`, but I'd have to do a lookup table of the same kind - storing the stuff in holdspace. Plus, any regex is only going to wind up doing more of the same at the bottom-line - but it might do it on *every line*. It's better to do the hard part first - generating your search matches all at once - *and then* do the search. In that way, the search engine does not have to reparse the search match on every line.

Comment: You make an excellent point. I was operating under the impression that a regex equivalent to the family would be the most elegant solution, but failed to appreciate that constructing the family as a set of string literals would be computationally much less expensive, and moreover that the *difference* in computational overhead between the two approaches would scale with the size of the file to be examined.

Comment: @user001 - precisely. In my opinion, the words *elegant* and *computation* don't even belong in the same dictionary, let alone the same sentence. The computer is a very stupid machine. It cannot count higher than one. Everything it does it brute forced - always. Abstractions always only amount to more brute work in the end. The only thing it's got going for it is that it is really really fast at being stupid.

Comment: @user001 - upon a little further consideration though, I can agree with you that it is always fun to try.

Comment: Yes, the attempt can be enjoyable as a thought exercise, though in the end, our goal as a programmer, as you have noted, must be efficiency.